# Trigger are not rendering properly in tabpanel extjs3.4

Tags: triggers, extjs3, tabpanel

**This problem is only in IE. The triggers in Tab1 are getting rendered after Tab2 is rendered. This is only for IE, it is working fine in firefox**

I am having a Tabpanel in which there are two tabs are there let say tab1 and tab2.
In Tab1 there is a tool bar in centre region of two regions(west, centre). For the tool bar i am adding the triggers with the width 150 each and tab2 is having its panel without triggers or tool bar.

Now my problem is when i place Tab1 is active the trigger is rendering perfectly but if i place the Tab2 as active directly after starting the application the trigger in the Tab1 is not rendering properly.

The trigger is rendering like that it's width is 0.